# Singleton with Reference Variable

Tags: c++, singleton

I need several unique objects which are always available as program runs. I followed the Singleton design pattern and it suggests using method `getInstance()`to fetch the objects. But I prefer to retrieve the objects immediately without calling method. So I wrote a class which provides several unique objects returned by reference type instead of pointer.

```
class Priority
{
public:
    static Priority &High;
    static Priority &Medium;
    static Priority &Low;

    std::string getName(void);
    int getLevel(void);

private:
   Priority(int level, std::string const& name);
   ~Priority();
   Priority(Priority const&);
   const Priority &operator = (Priority const&);

   int level_;
   std::string name_;
};

Priority &Priority::High   = Priority(3, "High");
Priority &Priority::Medium = Priority(2, "Medium");
Priority &Priority::Low    = Priority(1, "Low");

Priority::Priority(int level, std::string const& name)
   : level_(level), name_(name)
{ }

Priority::~Priority() { }

inline std::string Priority::getName(void)
{
    return name_;
}

inline int Priority::getLevel(void)
{
    return level_;
}
```

I wrote an example program that uses the above class.

```
int main()
{
    Priority &m = Priority::High;
    std::string name = m.getName();
    int level = m.getLevel();
    return 0;
}
```

The program worked fine. Hence I assumed the memory allocated for variable
`Priority &Priority::High = Priority(3, "High");`won't be wiped out until the program stops or dll file storing the class is unloaded. Am I correct?

Comment: You could just store the object instead of reference if you're not sure..

Comment: I used reference because I want to keep the unique objects from copying themselves each time I call them. Priority m = Priority::High will return the a copy of Priority::High, really waste memory.

Comment: But you have already hidden the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem.

The code you've shown shouldn't compile: you can't bind a reference to non-`const` to an rvalue.

Examples with Visual C++ 11.0 and g++ 4.7.1:

```
[D:\dev\test]
> cl foo.cpp
foo.cpp
foo.cpp(27) : warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'Priority' to 'Priority &'
        A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
foo.cpp(28) : warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'Priority' to 'Priority &'
        A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
foo.cpp(29) : warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'initializing' : conversion from 'Priority' to 'Priority &'
        A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue

[D:\dev\test]
> gnuc foo.cpp
foo.cpp:27:48: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Priority&' from an rvalue of type 'Priority'
foo.cpp:28:50: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Priority&' from an rvalue of type 'Priority'
foo.cpp:29:47: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Priority&' from an rvalue of type 'Priority'

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

---

### Tool usage.

With Visual C++, use option **`/W4`** (warning level 4) to get the warnings shown above.

You can put this and other “make it standard-conforming” options in the environment variable **`CL`** (and ditto, **`LINK`** for the Microsoft linker, e.g. `/entry:mainCRTStartup` as a default linker option).

```
[D:\dev\test]
> echo %CL%
/nologo /EHsc /GR /W4 /FI"progrock/cppx/macro/c++11.for_msvc_11.h"

[D:\dev\test]
> _
```

---

### C++ fix for the problem.

Instead of lvalue references you could use rvalue references, but although Visual C++ is happy with that, g++ then complains about the private destructor.

So intead of the reference idea – what purpose was it meant to serve? – you can simply use ordinary static data members.

However, with ordinary static data members, as opposed to e.g. Meyers' singletons, you run the risk of banging into the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). So if you absolutely must provide globals, I recommend using singletons for that. And as for the kind of singleton, using the simplest possible solution is often the best, which means [Meyers' singletons](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/C-plus-plus-In-Theory-The-Singleton-Pattern-Part-I/4/) (I just linked the first reasonably-looking google result).

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop with Platform Toolset Windows7.1SDK. It compiled without any problems in both Debug and Release modes. I tried again using MinGW and it showed the results you posted above.

Comment: @user1853288: you need to up your visual c++ warning level, as explained in the answer. you can adjust that in the visual studio project settings (properties dialog).

Comment: Thank you all. Maybe I should stick to original singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't even compile, you're initialising the references with temporary objects. However, you don't need references there at all; just declare the static members as the objects directly:

**In header:**

```
class Priority
{
public:
    static Priority High;
    static Priority Medium;
    static Priority Low;
//...
};
```

**In source file:**

```
Priority Priority::High(3, "High");
Priority Priority::Medium(2, "Medium");
Priority Priority::Low(1, "Low");
```